# Рекурсивный метод поиска файлов не правильно отрабатывает

Tags: java

есть метод:

```
public class MyClass{
private int count=0;
        private void search(File file) {
            File[] file1 = file.listFiles();
            try {
                for (File t : file1) {
                     if (t.isFile()&&!t.isHidden()) {
                        count++;
                    } else if (t.isDirectory()) {
                        search(t);

                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException | SecurityException r) {
            }
        }
}
```

метод рабочий,всё считает правильно, но при больших объемах пересчитывает файлы.

взял для примера мой жесткий диск, посчитал все папки по отдельности, перепроверил с windows(выбор папок`-->`пкм`-->`свойства, в свойтвах написано сколько файлов и папок) и вот по отдельности цифра 90364, но если запустить полностью на жесткий диск, то цифра уже 90556.
в чем проблема?

Comment: `private void count = 0` <—— что это? Добавьте пример вызова метода и убедитесь, что а) код компилируется б) ошибка воспроизводится при использовании приведенного, отредактированного кода.

Comment: Гипотеза: сейчас код глотает исключения, попробуйте что-нибудь выводить в `catch`.

Comment: @defaultlocale метод работает, это я его не правильно тут оформил, я извиняюсь.Вот сейчас его вид достойный, как у меня.

Comment: @defaultlocale если выводить что нибудь в catch то будут выскакивать Nullpointerexception
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

Comment: "... одна цифра, ... то цифра уже совсем другая" - ну и объявили бы эти "цифры". Что за необъяснимая потребность темнить?

Comment: Не советую проверять на папке Windows. В ней куча файлов с железными ссылками. Попробуйте для начала на более безопасной папке, у которой и проблем с правами доступа не будет =/

Comment: @Mr.Modest нет, я это тестил не на папке windows, это я количество файлов в папке с его помощью проверил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему бы не использовать уже готовый метод walk (примеры для Java 1.8)?
[Доки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Или же find

```
Files.find(Paths.get(path),
       Integer.MAX_VALUE,
       (filePath, fileAttr) -> fileAttr.isRegularFile())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Для Вашей задачи

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(paths))
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .count()
```

или

```
Files.find(Paths.get(path),
            Integer.MAX_VALUE,
            (filePath, fileAttr) -> fileAttr.isRegularFile())
            .count()
```

Comment: ваш метод хороший но баг тоже присутствует

Comment: @Vlad< А вы не могли подумать, что он также считает и скрытые файлы?

Comment: В чем проблемы? Просто добавьте filter  с !Files.isHidden(path) (только придется сделать там блок try-catch или обернуть в метод